# Webpack 5 with html-loader gives ReferenceError

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, webpack-html-loader

I'm trying to run a hello world app in Angular 12 + webpack 5.  When I try to add `html-loader` (as all the guides say i should), I get the error below.

Why does this happen?  and how can I fix it?

If you'd like to replicate the situation, please see the [GitHub repo here](https://github.com/prestto/tilt_angular), and run the command `npm run start`.

```
ERROR in   Error: /opt/tp/projects/tilt_angular/front/src/index.html:127
  /******/  __webpack_require__.b = require("url").pathToFileURL(__filename);
                                                                 ^
  ReferenceError: __filename is not defined
  
  - index.html:127 
    /opt/tp/projects/tilt_angular/front/src/index.html:127:65
  
  - index.html:146 
    /opt/tp/projects/tilt_angular/front/src/index.html:146:13
  
  - index.html:156 
    /opt/tp/projects/tilt_angular/front/src/index.html:156:12
  
  - index.js:327 HtmlWebpackPlugin.evaluateCompilationResult
    [front]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:327:28
  
  - index.js:243 
    [front]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:243:22
  
  - runMicrotasks
  
  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
  
  - async Promise.all
  
  - async Promise.all
```

Webpack conf:

```
const path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './src/main.ts',
    polyfills: './src/polyfills.ts',
    // vendor: './src/vendor.ts',
  },
  mode: 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading html-webpack-plugin.